# href with id redirect to a page and change the class to active

Tags: javascript, html, css, bootstrap-4

I have two pages one is the home page and another is the contact us page the contact us page has 4 menus in which 1st one is active. I want that when I click on the home page button it goes to the contact us page and makes 2nd option active.

Home page button code:

```
<div class="buttons">
<a class="btn btn-danger" href="javascript:void(0)" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#exampleModalLong">Book A Service</a>
</div>
```

Contact us menu code:

```
<div class="nav flex-column nav-pills nav-pills-custom" id="v-pills-tab" role="tablist" aria-orientation="vertical">
                    <a class="nav-link mb-2 p-3 shadow active" id="v-pills-profile-tab" data-toggle="pill" href="#v-pills-profile" role="tab" aria-controls="v-pills-profile" aria-selected="true" data-kmt="1">
                        <i class="fa fa-calendar-minus-o mr-2"></i>
                        <span class="text-uppercase">Book a Service</span></a>

                    <a class="nav-link mb-2 p-3 shadow" id="v-pills-home-tab" data-toggle="pill" href="#v-pills-home" role="tab" aria-controls="v-pills-home" aria-selected="false" data-kmt="1">
                        <i class="fa fa-car" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                        <span class=" text-uppercase">Guest Book</span></a>

                    <a class="nav-link mb-2 p-3 shadow" id="v-pills-messages-tab" data-toggle="pill" href="#v-pills-messages" role="tab" aria-controls="v-pills-messages" aria-selected="false" data-kmt="1">
                        <i class="fa fa-question" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                        <span class="text-uppercase">Buy a Car</span></a>

                    <a class="nav-link mb-2 p-3 shadow" id="v-pills-settings-tab" data-toggle="pill" href="#v-pills-settings" role="tab" aria-controls="v-pills-settings" aria-selected="false" data-kmt="1">
                        <i class="fa fa-check mr-2"></i>
                        <span class="text-uppercase">Exchange your Car</span></a>
                </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

this method is longer but it is worked

```
        <div class="nav flex-column nav-pills nav-pills-custom" id="v-pills-tab" role="tablist" aria-orientation="vertical">
            <a class="nav-link mb-2 p-3 shadow active book_service" id="v-pills-profile-tab" data-toggle="pill" href="#v-pills-profile" role="tab" aria-controls="v-pills-profile" aria-selected="true" data-kmt="1">
                <i class="fa fa-calendar-minus-o mr-2"></i>
                <span class="text-uppercase">Book a Service</span></a>
            <a class="nav-link mb-2 p-3 shadow GuestBook" id="v-pills-home-tab" data-toggle="pill" href="#v-pills-home" role="tab" aria-controls="v-pills-home" aria-selected="false" data-kmt="1">
                <i class="fa fa-car" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                <span class=" text-uppercase">Guest Book</span></a>
            <a class="nav-link mb-2 p-3 shadow BuyAcar" id="v-pills-messages-tab" data-toggle="pill" href="#v-pills-messages" role="tab" aria-controls="v-pills-messages" aria-selected="false" data-kmt="1">
                <i class="fa fa-question" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                <span class="text-uppercase">Buy a Car</span></a>
            <a class="nav-link mb-2 p-3 shadow Ex_Car" id="v-pills-settings-tab" data-toggle="pill" href="#v-pills-settings" role="tab" aria-controls="v-pills-settings" aria-selected="false" data-kmt="1">
                <i class="fa fa-check mr-2"></i>
                <span class="text-uppercase">Exchange your Car</span></a>
        </div>


                   // add Book on Service page

                        $(document).ready(function()
                        {
                             $('.book_service').addClass('active');
                        });

                    // add on Guest Book page

                        $(document).ready(function()
                        {
                             $('.GuestBook').addClass('active');
                        });

                    // Buy a Car page

                        $(document).ready(function()
                        {
                             $('.BuyAcar').addClass('active');
                        });
```

Comment: Thank you for the help I got an idea but it's not working.